# Regular Expression splitting up of NSString - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

Split String using Regular Expression in iOS

I have solved this problem using loops, however would like a cleaner answer and I hope a reg exe guru can help me out.

**My original string could be like the following**

```
NSString *originalString = @"343 a mr smith needs this work";

NSString *originalStringVerTwo = @"345a mr jones needs this work as well";

NSString *originalStringVerThree = @"345 Mrs Someone";
```

I need to separate into 3 separate new strings:

- Number with or with a trailing "a" or "b", remove white space between if exists
- Person name, maybe capital or not, ie mr smith or Mrs Jones etc
- After this, zero or more words to be in the final string

**For example**

- 123a mr who here are some words
- 124 b mrs jones n/p
- 654 Mr Foo
- 123 Jones n/p
- 345 n/p

**Should result in the following**

*line 1*

```
NSString *one = 123a
NSString *two = mr who
NSString *three = here are some words
```

*line 2*

```
NSString *one = 124b // i want the white space removed between number and digit
NSString *two = mrs jones
NSString *three = n/p
```

*line 3*

```
NSString *one = 654
NSString *two = Mr Foo
NSString *three = @""
```

*line 4*

```
NSString *one = 123
NSString *two = Jones
NSString *three = n/p
```

*line 5*

```
NSString *one = 345
NSString *two = n/p
NSString *three = @""
```

The constants will be

1. 3 digit number with or without an "a" "b" (123, 123 a, 123b)
2. A persons name, with or without salutation (Mr jones, jones)
3. The persons name could be unknown - hence the exact text of "n/p"
4. Following the name is a string of n length that will end with a \n (this is a set of words\n).

**The removal of the white space from 123 a into 123a is ideal but not major requirement**

Comment: You should include your solution using loops. It is probably a good starting point for other answers.

Comment: Do you have a strict pattern for the name? What if my name was "Lady Clöe MᶜDougal" or "Κύριε Δημήτρης Παπαφιλίππου?"

Comment: @JamesWebster I think its to messy and would just confuse actually, hence the reason  why I wanna scrap it. The names are basic for what I need, i.e. mr jones (maybe capitals) with won't be like the examples you have shown. So a salutation and a surname. It may also be "n/p" (unknown name - exactly as shown n/p). There may or may not be a Mr / Mrs / Ms etc, could just be Jones. The name is always preceded by a 3 digit number (with or without a / b, ie 650;605a;605 b) Hope that helps add clarity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a regex that should work:

```
       ^             //start of line
       (             //first capture group
            [\d]+    //one or more digits
       )             //end of first capture group 

       (?:           //start of optional non-capturing group
              \s?    //optional whitespace
            (        //second capture group
              [ab]   //character class - a or b
            )        //end of second capture group 
       )?            //end of optional non-capturing group 

       \s            //whitespace

       (             //third capture group
            (?:      //non-capturing group
      Mr|Mrs|Mister  //title alternation
            )         
            \s       //whitespace
            [\w/]+   //1 or more word characters or "/"
       |             //alternation 
            [\w/]+   //1 or more word characters or "/"
       )             //end of third capture group 

       (?:           //start of optional non-capturing group  
            \s       //whitespace
            (        //fourth capture group
            .*       //0 or more of any character
            )        //end of fourth capture group
        )?           //end of optional non-capturing group
       $             //end of line
```

Construct your regex. We have to escape the escapes to retain them in an NSString:

```
NSString* regexString =
@"^([\\d]+(?:\\s?[ab])?)\\s((?:Mr|Ms|Mrs|Mister)\\s[\\w/]+|[\\w/]+)(?:\\s(.*))?$";

NSRegularExpression *regex =
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                     options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                     error:nil];
```

Make a test array:

```
NSArray* testArray = @[
                        @"123a mr who here are some words"
                       ,@"124 b mrs jones n/p"
                       ,@"654 Mr Foo"
                       ,@"123 Jones n/p"
                       ,@"345 n/p"
                       ,@"345"
                       ,@"nothing here"
                       ];
```

Process the test array:

```
for (NSString* string in testArray) {
    NSLog(@" ");
    NSLog(@"input: '%@'",string);

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,string.length);
    if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:range] == 1) {
        NSString* body = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                           options:0
                                             range:range
                                      withTemplate:@"$1\n$2\n$3"];


        NSArray* result = [body componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSString* one = result[0];
        NSString* two = result[1];
        NSString* three = result[2];
        NSLog(@"one:   '%@'",one);
        NSLog(@"two:   '%@'",two);
        NSLog(@"three: '%@'",three);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no match");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    input: '123a mr who here are some words'
    one:   '123a'
    two:   'mr who'
    three: 'here are some words'

    input: '124 b mrs jones n/p'
    one:   '124b'
    two:   'mrs jones'
    three: 'n/p'

    input: '654 Mr Foo'
    one:   '654'
    two:   'Mr Foo'
    three: ''

    input: '123 Jones n/p'
    one:   '123'
    two:   'Jones'
    three: 'n/p'

    input: '345 n/p'
    one:   '345'
    two:   'n/p'
    three: ''

    input: '345'
    no match

    input: 'nothing here'
    no match
```

Comment: Thank to so much. What an elegant solution compared to my loops etc. You are a RegEx Guru!

Comment: Great documentation of your regex anatomy.